# How to clear python screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I need to clear the screen of python.

This is the coding screen I need to code it with:

[image: Here is the code]

And the window that opens when I press "run" and "run module" is what I need to clear

I have said this in the way I did so not to cause any confusion.
I am NOT using the black code runner (The one with the black background).

```
import os
os.system("cls")
```

That does not work as it just opens and immediately closes the black code runner

I am using Windows and python version 3.4.3

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Python itself does not have "run" or "run module" buttons (or even a screen).

Comment: Ifyou  look at the picture at the top there is the "run" button

Comment: That looks likt Tk, post the code you use to generate the window.

Comment: Wait, __the black code runner__???!! Do you mean _'the console'_?

Comment: i would assume so

Comment: Subprocess also does not work

Comment: what do you mean by "closes the black code runner"? Command Prompt? Console? Terminal? Is there some specific IDE you are using?

Comment: Note: Stack Overflow is *not the place* for urgent requests. We are building a repository of knowledge for the long term, with quality questions and even better answers. The word 'urgent' has no place in such questions.

Comment: Thanks for telling me should I remove that from the title?

Comment: I've already done so for you. You are using IDLE, so I duped you to the canonical question on how to clear the IDLE shell.

Comment: I am trying to avoid adding lots of new lines @MartijnPieters

Comment: That is all that works from that other question therefore there is no correct answer for this question there @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Programmingmann: Are you actually calling the `import os; os.system('cls')`? Share with us the complete code where you used it? Because I do not see it in the current code

Comment: Yes I did use that code @anonymous

Comment: But the question is where? It will be helpful if you can paste your complete code over here

Comment: I have haven't I? If you don't think so can you please edit the question to show that please @anonymous

Comment: The code where you have written `os.system('cls')`. Am I missing anything? In your code I can only see `print()` and `input()`. Do you expect me to hack into your machine, copy the code and paste it over here?

Comment: Also why have you still got this marked as duplicate @MartijnPieters I have already told you I have looked and the answer is not there. It only suggests adding lots of new lines which I do not wish to do - It is not "actually clearing the screen"

Comment: Oh yes sorry @anonymous the image. I will add the correct image in now

Comment: @Programmingmann: this is the same question. If there is no satisfying answer there you won't find one here either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please can you unmark this as duplicate and give this question a chance incase anyone new sees this and finds an answer

Comment: @anonymous How is that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Plese open this post again, someone may have the correct answer that I am looking for but cannot post it, plus it is still not a duplicate. If you still think it is please explain why

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your code that you forgot to import the `os` module first, add this at the beginning of the file:

```
import os
```

Edit: it may have to be `os.system('cls')`

Edit2: After some testing around it looks like the default Python interpreter accepts:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
```

Comment: That still does not work - nothing happens

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Oh ok, well thanks for trying to help me anyway :) @SpaceW189